# How do I use join twice with the same table in JPQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two queries in JPQL which join with an entity. I need to get the assets that are in both results (i.e. join with the same table twice).

The first query gives me a list of Asset that have a certain property:

```
select distinct(a) from Asset a join a.properties p where p.name = :name
```

The second query gives me a list of Asset to which I have access:

```
select distinct(assets) from Asset assets inner join assets.groups assetgroups inner join assetgroups.permissions permissions inner join permissions.usrGroups usergroups with usergroups.id in :groups
```

I would need a list of Asset to which I have access AND with that property name. I am using Hibernate as JPA back-end. I've tried several options but have been so far unsuccessful. How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that `Asset` has id field named `assetId` this should work:

```
select asset from Asset asset
WHERE asset.assetId in (select distinct(a.assetId) from Asset a join a.properties p where p.name = :name)
AND asset.assetId in (select distinct(a.assetId) from Asset a inner join a.groups assetgroups inner join assetgroups.permissions permissions inner join permissions.usrGroups usergroups with usergroups.id in :groups)
```

Comment: THIS! Thank you. I like how the solution is actually simple and makes sense. Just tried it and it worked perfectly. Also it translates to only one SQL query.

Comment: For the sake of discussion: Would UNION work too? If so, would this solution be better than using UNION?

Comment: @Calabacin JPQL has no `UNION`.