SQL UPDATE rows on same table with parent-child relationship
Given the example table below (which is a very small-scale version), I am trying to update the owner name on a row based on the user input of a single ownerId and multiple workIds. However, there is some extra criteria where if a workId being updated has a parentItemId with associated children itemIds, those with children itemIds should be updated as well.



workId
owner
ownerId
itemId
parentItemId




1
Bob
23
123
123


2
Bob
23
234
123


3
Tom
35
345
123


4
Tom
35
789
789


5
Joe
44
567
789


6
Joe
44
678
789



For example, let's say as a user I provide the following update request, given there is another owner named John with an ownerId of 56:
{ ownerIdReq: 56, workIdsReq: [1] }
With that request, the table should update workId 1 to John, but also workId 2 and 3 as well, since workId 1 has an itemId of 123 which is a parentItemId, and workId 2 and 3 have parentItemId as 123. The table would update as follows:



workId
owner
ownerId
itemId
parentItemId




1
John
56
123
123


2
John
56
234
123


3
John
56
345
123


4
Tom
35
789
789


5
Joe
44
567
789


6
Joe
44
678
789



As for the SQL, it is pretty simple in terms of updating based on the workId:
UPDATE table SET ownerId = ownerIdReq WHERE workId IN workIdsReq
Where I run into issues is my thought process on updating the children which have a parentItemId of another row being updated. I can get the parentItemIds with something like:
SELECT parentItemId FROM table WHERE workId IN workIdsReq
I'm just not sure how to get the parentIds of the workIds being updated, then use those parentIds to look for itemIds and update them. I am having trouble translating this into SQL. Can this be done in a single query, or is that not possible? I would appreciate any tips or suggestions.

Use a self-JOIN to match the parent-child relationship.
UPDATE table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.parentItemId = t2.itemId
SET t1.ownerId = ownerIdReq
WHERE t2.workdId IN workdIdsReq

DEMO

This works perfect, thank you. However, is there a way to write this where the JOIN is included after the WHERE clause? I'm using JPA/Hibernate and there are some restrictions when writing the query. It will not let me have two references of the same table for some reason.

No, SQL syntax is not that flexible. The order of clauses is precisely defined.

Are you sure it's set up for MySQL? Different SQL dialects have different ways of implementing joins in UPDATE queries.

Good question. I am fairly new to this so I would not be surprised if it is not set up for that. I am trying to use the answer referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621608/how-do-i-use-join-twice-with-the-same-table-in-jpql

I suggest you ask a new question with the jpa tag so someone familiar can help you with converting this to its syntax.
